# How to recognize previous screen name in React-Navigation?

Tags: react-native

Now I have 3 screens in my simple App - firstScreen, secondScreen, thirdScreen.
In the firstScreen, there is a button - "Go back to previous screen!".
In the secondScreen and thirdScreen, there is a button - "Go to firstScreen".
When I navigate to firstScreen from second or third screen, how to know previous screen name?
I'd like to show alert in the firstScreen like this - "You are from secondScreen" or "You are from thirdScreen".
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest ways I can think about is by passing parameters when navigating like it's described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params).

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            fromScreen: 'screen 1',
          });
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you devcrp. It helped me very much.